# Remove specific class when button/dropdown click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove specific class ("help-text"). when user click on button specific class will be removed.

Here is my code

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="img/find-match.png"/>
        <span class="help-text">Click Here</span>
    </button>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!jQuery(e.target).hasClass('dropdown-lg')) {
        jQuery('.dropdown-lg').removeClass('help-text');
    }
});
</script>
```

Kindly advice me any solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `span` with `help-text`, is inside the button. So you can use,

```
$(e.target).find('.help-text').removeClass('help-text')
```

or

```
$('.help-text',e.target).removeClass('help-text')
```

Also, instead of handling click on `document` I would suggest,,

```
$('button.dropdown-toggle').click(...
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/401/)**

```
$('button.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.help-text').toggleClass('help-text')
});
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the class, or remove the element? This works ay my end. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/401/

Comment: when user click on button class is removed but when user again click on button for hide div then class is not set back

Answer (score 1):

SInce `.help-text` is a child of the `button`, use [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
jQuery('.dropdown-lg').find('.help-text').removeClass('help-text');
```

```js
jQuery('.dropdown-lg').click(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).find('.help-text').removeClass('help-text');
});
```

```css
.help-text {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <img src="img/find-match.png" /><span class="help-text">Click Here</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: OH, sorry, had a typo, changed `removeClass` to `find` for the first call

Comment: @dev, see the working example in my answer. It is in the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('button.btn').click(function (e) {
        if (jQuery(this).find('.help-text').length) {
            jQuery('.help-text').removeClass('help-text');
        }
    });
```

Comment: when user click on button class is removed but when user again click on button for hide div then class is not set back. I only want to removed class/element on click.